# extended class, doesn't have its own methods

Tags: javascript, class, extends

I try to extend a class with another, who has its constructor overrode, but when i instance this class, it doesn't have its own methods, but has its own properties.

Here's an example which doesn't work properly:

```js
class A {
    constructor () {
        return {
            pi: 3.14
        }
    }
}

class B extends A {     
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.c = 10;
    }

    d () {}
}

let b = new B();  
console.log(b);
```

Here, b is :

```
Object {
    c:10,
    pi:3.14 
}
```

So why the '`d`' method is missing ?

**EDIT:**

Here is a concrete case:

I need to extend a class with HTMLElement, which i can instance and use like html element without registering with document.registerElement.

My code is:

```
class Element{

    constructor(){

        return document.createElement('div');

    }

}


class Editor extends Element{


    constructor(){

        super();

    }

}
```

and i want to use my class like this:

```
let editor = new Editor();

document.querySelector('body').appendChild(editor);
```

Comment: because you're returning custom object from A's constructor, just change `return` to `this.pi = 3.14`

Comment: Of course, but it's just an example. In this case, i really need to return an object.
My class needs to extend an object who's not extendable. So this is the only solution i found.

Comment: Sure, then I guess it is better to describe your particular case, not just abstract example.

It is happening because object with method `d()` created first, but then it lost, because you returning new object with `pi` property.

Comment: I have edit my post, with my code.

Comment: To be honest, I'd prefer aggregation instead of inheritance here.

Answer (score -1):

ECMAScript6 class methods are methods of an object's prototype object. You will find the method not in the object itself, but in `obj.__proto__`.

https://reinteractive.com/posts/235-es6-classes-and-javascript-prototypes

Here you can see and maybe understand what is going on internally with prototyped objects. And yes, the ES6 syntax is just a syntax change, not a new technology.